# Best setting for taking a moving car and capture plate at night - rpi3 raspicam v2

Tags: raspicam

I want some help to set the best settings for getting a video at night of a moving car without blur (I need to see the plate)
I'm using an external IR illuminator, so the plate is brights.
I'm using an rpi3 with a raspicam v2 noir.
I tried multiple configurations with more or less the same results.

sensor mode: 6
resolution: 640x480
framerate : 80
iso: 400
shutter: 330000

Comment: This question as phrased is probably too broad for any SE site. If you can make it more specific and provide some code, you might be able to make it fit better at https://stackoverflow.com/questions, where you'll get more programmers looking at it. Nothing about this question really deals specifically with Raspberry Pi, at least as it's written now.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce blur by reducing the exposure time. Try setting shorted shutter time, negative EV correction or using a special exposure mode optimized for shooting moving objects (usually called "kids" or "sports"). [`raspivid`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md) provides options for EV correction (e.g. `-ev -20`) and exposure (e.g. `-ex sports`) you could try.

Another option is to take still pictures out of (or instead of) your video, then use image-processing software capable of *motion deblurring*. In Linux, the two available alternatives I know are [Unshake](https://unshake.en.softonic.com/) and [Refocus](http://refocus.sourceforge.net/).